# Google Sheets script to copy/paste from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Could someone help me with creating a script that does the following:

Function: Upon adding a new sheet to my already existing workbook, I would like it to copy Column "E" from Sheet 1 and (Paste Special > Conditional formatting only) to the newly introduced Sheet "X"

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far. Sorry, no one is going to write the whole code for you, and you just copy and paste then.

Answer (score 1):

Where can I learn more on how to write code? I have never used Stackoverflow by the way someone just recommended me to come here. I believe I just answered my own question somehow on the post, which I am sure was wrong to do but I couldn't comment on an already existing answer without exceeding the limit.

```
// Adds custom menu
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('CustomMenu').addItem('Copy format', 'copyFormat') //Add function to menu.'GIVE NAME HERE', 'functionName' 

    .addToUi();  

}


function copyFormat() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sh1 = ss.getSheets()[0]; //Gets the first sheet of the workbook. Can use ss.getSheetByName('Name of sheet here'); If it is not the first sheet
  var activeSh = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Get the active sheet, you should be on the sheet just added
  var rowEnd = activeSh.getLastRow(); //Last row of active sheet


  sh1.getRange("E1:E").copyFormatToRange(activeSh, 5, 5, 1, rowEnd); //Copy format, including conditional, to column E of active sheet


}
```

This just adds a button that allows you to select a cell and give it the same conditions has in the original sheet.

Example: Sheet 1: Column E1:E100 has a given condition.. which needs to apply in the exact same way to any new incoming sheets since they all come in the same format. Right now its at a point of which when a new sheet arrives in the workbook: I can enter the new sheet > Select the cell which requires the conditions > Select the custom menu > Cell gets conditioned. So the next step would be automate the process I just mentioned since there is several sheets added daily to the workbook.